# weired beahviour when setting value of primefaces spinner using javascript

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

sorry for the vague title.

basically what I am trying to achieve is having 2  one for max and one for min value.

So my xhtml looks like follows:

```
<p:outputLabel for="max" value="Maximum Occurance: " />
<p:spinner id='max' min="1"  maxlength="3" size="3" value="#{ObjectDefinitionBean.max}" />

<p:outputLabel for="min" value="Minimum Occurance: " />
<p:spinner id='min' min="0"  maxlength="3" size="3" value="#{ObjectDefinitionBean.min}" />
```

I then addef ollowing javascript which basically checks if max>min and if not so sets the max value to the new min value, and the other eways round:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
//<![CDATA[
$("#ioDefCreation\\:max_input").change(function(){
    var min = parseInt($("#ioDefCreation\\:min_input").val());
    var max = parseInt($("#ioDefCreation\\:max_input").val());
    if(min>max){
        $("#ioDefCreation\\:min_input").val(max);
    }
});

$("#ioDefCreation\\:min_input").change(function(){
    var min = parseInt($("#ioDefCreation\\:min_input").val());
    var max = parseInt($("#ioDefCreation\\:max_input").val());
    if(max<min){
        $("#ioDefCreation\\:max_input").val(min);
    }
});
//]]>
</script>
```

So far everything wworks as intenden with the exception of a weired behaviour:
lets say at the beginning both values are 0
I increase the minimum by 4 (by clicking the up arrow of the spinner)
Now tha maximum shows 4 correctly. However if I now click the up arrow of the max it will display 1 (incrementing 1 from its initial value 0 instead of the value that was set using javascript). This is not limited to the case that the initial values are 0. it will reset the value of min and max to the values they where before they where altered via the javascript functions.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because in your code the minimum value of max is 1. When you set it to 0 using javascript, primefaces takes over control and sets it to the minimum specified value

> `<p:spinner id='max' !!!min="1"!!!  maxlength="3" size="3"
>   value="#{ObjectDefinitionBean.max}" />`

Comment: I am not trying to set it to zero. I am trying to increment from the value set by javascript when incrementing the min value above the max value. So the min value is lets say 10. so the max value is automatically set to 10 however when i click one of the arrows of the spinner. the value of max is reset to its value before it was changed via the min becomming larger than the max.. if that makes any sence to you :-)

Comment: ah, alright, i finally got it :D once you click the arrow the value gets updated from the backing java bean. try updating your bean value aswell in your javascript function like this:

var foo; 

<h:outputText value="#{formBean.setValue(foo)}" />;

Comment: accordsing to chrome dev tool network monitoring, there is no communication between the frontend and the backing bean. but i could try adding a onchangelistener